# printf format string: order of arguments and Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, printf

I get a segmentation fault if i change the order of the arguments in a `printf` format string.

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    _uint64 test_var = 50000000;
    char str[20] = { };
    sprintf( str, "TEST_STRING" );

    printf( "test_var %lld str %s\n", test_var, str ); //OK
    printf( "str %s test_var %d\n", str, test_var ); //OK
    printf( "test_var %d str %s\n", test_var, str ); //Segmentation Fault

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Why am i getting this fault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 64-bit value is 64 bits (8 bytes). An `int` (which is what the format specifier `"%d"` uses) is 32 bits (4 bytes).

So what `printf` does in the crashing line is to read 4 bytes to print as an integer, then it will read the remaining four bytes (on a 32-bit system) or the remaining four bytes and the first four bytes of the string pointer (on a 64-bit system) to use as the string pointer. That string pointer is, as you can understand, not a valid pointer, and so you have *undefined behavior* which in your case leads to a crash.

Comment: Actually, for most 64 bit code, it will silently work. A 32bit integer would be expanded to 64 bit before use in the call. Obviously, on most other systems the UB is not masked.

Comment: _uint64 test_var1 = 0xaaaabbbbccccdddd;

_uint32 test_var2 = 0x30;

printf( "Result: test_var1=0x%x test_var2=0x%x test_var2=0x%x\n", test_var1, test_var2, test_var2 );

Result: test_var1=0xccccdddd test_var2=0xaaaabbbb test_var2=0x30

Answer (score 1):

```
printf( "test_var %d str %s\n", test_var, str ); //Segmentation Fault
                  ^^
```

You should use `%lld`.